# Counting number of transactions within past 5 minutes on a particular day, at a particular store, at a particular terminal within the past 5 minutes

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to count the number of transactions that happened in the past 5 minutes from the current transaction.

```
CALL_DAY    TRANS_TIME  STORE_NUM   TERMINAL    CUSTOMER_NUMBER
20130201    10:46:04    1111               1                  1
20130202    17:09:19    1111               2                  2
20130202    17:10:30    2222               3                  3
20130202    17:11:35    2222               3                  3
20130202    17:13:26    2222               3                  4
```

Above are all separate transactions that occurred. I am trying to find how many transactions occurred on a specific day, at a specific store number, at a specific terminal within the past 5 minutes and create a column for each row that states that number for each transaction.

So far I have converted the date and time to a datetime function (shown below). I then tried to use a DATEADD function but this did not accomplish what I was trying to find out.  Does anybody know how this can be accomplished?

```
/* Converting to DATETIME */
Data NEW_FILE ; 
SET DATA.MY_FILE; 
new_call_day = input(compress(call_day),yymmdd8.);  
format new_call_day date9.;                         
new_time = input(compress(trans_time), HHMMSS8.);   
format new_time HHMM5.;                            
dtetime  = dhms(compress(new_call_day),0,0,compress(new_time)); 
format dtetime datetime22.                                
RUN;
```

After this I tried a DATEADD but it did not create a column for each that I wanted.  I am stuck... Maybe I approached it wrong?

Comment: I haven't a clue what you mean by 'tried a DATEADD'.  That's not a SAS function...

Comment: How much data are you looking at?  Is this millions of rows? Billions?

Comment: It would help to see some sample output data...how you would expect the above sample input data to be processed

Comment: DATEADD is a SQL SERVER function, the equivalent in SAS is INTCK.

Comment: What you're trying to do is not trivial, even if you're pretty decent at SAS. Joe's question about the number of rows is important because this could take some processing power with a large data set. Subtracting 5 minutes from each transaction's datetime is trivial (`dtetime - dhms(0,0,5,0)`) but once you get that, the rest is significantly more complex. Is this really what you need or is this a way to get to some other result?

Comment: i am working with around 100K Rows.  Sorry I wasn't exact, I tried using DATEADD bc SAS or SQL can either be used.

Comment: Hmmmm.... dang this is making my bang my head on my desk :(

Comment: probackpacker - this is really what I need.  I am looking for the count of transactions within the past 5 minutes of each transaction.  
I can work with a smaller dataset.  This is killing me... ive been trying hard to accomplish this but getting nowhere

Comment: You can use an ampersand to ensure that a user receives your message, like this: @probackpacker (probackpacker will now have a notification in his/her inbox that you attempted to communicate)

Answer (score 3):

### TL; DR

Use a SQL subquery. They are fast (especially if you can pass execution off to the DBMS) and easy to maintain.

```sas
PROC SQL NOPRINT;

    CREATE TABLE Work.TransWithCount AS
    SELECT      STORE_NUM
            ,   TERMINAL
            ,   TRANS_DT
            ,   (
                    SELECT      COUNT(*)
                    FROM        Work.Trans AS T
                    WHERE       T.STORE_NUM = P.STORE_NUM
                            AND T.TERMINAL = P.TERMINAL
                            AND T.TRANS_DT >= P.START_DT
                            AND T.TRANS_DT <= P.END_DT
                ) AS TRANS_COUNT
    FROM        Work.Trans AS P
    ;    

QUIT;
```

A non-SQL approach is also possible, but it's much more complicated. See the update below.

### Main

I can't promise that this will execute quickly, but in terms of code this is actually a rather trivial SQL statement. If you can pass the SQL off to the database server you might be able to achieve some performance gain by taking advantage of table indexes.

The approach below works exclusively on the SAS server. It creates three new columns: one combining the day and time into a single value (which makes it simpler to deal with transactions near midnight) and a start and end column which will be used to connect transactions that are near each other. You can easily modify the start and end if, for example, you'd like to count transactions within five minutes of each other (+/- 5 minutes) rather than just prior transactions 5 minutes (-5 minutes).

Here I am creating a sample dataset that is identical to your example:

```sas
DATA Work.Trans;

    INPUT   CALL_DAY        B8601DA8.   +1
            TRANS_TIME      HHMMSS8.
            STORE_NUM       
            TERMINAL        
            CUSTOMER_NUMBER 
            ;

    FORMAT  CALL_DAY        MMDDYY10.
            TRANS_TIME      TIME10.
            STORE_NUM       
            TERMINAL        
            CUSTOMER_NUMBER 
            ;

DATALINES;
20130201 10:46:04 1111 1 1
20130202 17:09:19 1111 2 2
20130202 17:10:30 2222 3 3
20130202 17:11:35 2222 3 3
20130202 17:13:26 2222 3 4
RUN;
```

Now I am going to create the three new columns and drop the day and time columns:

```sas
DATA Work.Trans;
    SET Work.Trans;

    FORMAT  START_DT        DATETIME18.
            END_DT          DATETIME18.
            TRANS_DT        DATETIME18.
            ;

    TRANS_DT = DHMS( CALL_DAY,
                     HOUR(TRANS_TIME),
                     MINUTE(TRANS_TIME),
                     SECOND(TRANS_TIME) );

    START_DT = TRANS_DT - '00:05:00't;
    END_DT = TRANS_DT;

    DROP    CALL_DAY
            TRANS_TIME
            ;

RUN;
```

Finally, I will create a simple SQL statement which executes a subquery on the same dataset. The subquery will, for each row in the parent set, simply find matching records based on the store and terminal IDs and the start and end dates (compared to the transaction date):

```sas
PROC SQL NOPRINT;

    CREATE TABLE Work.TransWithCount AS
    SELECT      STORE_NUM
            ,   TERMINAL
            ,   TRANS_DT
            ,   (
                    SELECT      COUNT(*)
                    FROM        Work.Trans AS T
                    WHERE       T.STORE_NUM = P.STORE_NUM
                            AND T.TERMINAL = P.TERMINAL
                            AND T.TRANS_DT >= P.START_DT
                            AND T.TRANS_DT <= P.END_DT
                ) AS TRANS_COUNT
    FROM        Work.Trans AS P
    ;


QUIT;
```

Voilà! You now have the following dataset ready to go:

```
┌───────────┬──────────┬────────────────────┬─────────────┐
│ STORE_NUM │ TERMINAL │           TRANS_DT │ TRANS_COUNT │
├───────────┼──────────┼────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│      1111 │        1 │ 01Feb2013 10:46:04 │           1 │
│      1111 │        2 │ 02Feb2013 17:09:19 │           1 │
│      2222 │        3 │ 02Feb2013 17:10:30 │           1 │
│      2222 │        3 │ 02Feb2013 17:11:35 │           2 │
│      2222 │        3 │ 02Feb2013 17:13:26 │           3 │
└───────────┴──────────┴────────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

**EDIT**
I just noticed that the TRANS_COUNT will also count the parent row. If that's a problem for you, then no "biggie": just subtract the count by 1 to ensure you are only counting *other* transactions:

```sas
PROC SQL NOPRINT;

    CREATE TABLE Work.TransWithCount AS
    SELECT      STORE_NUM
            ,   TERMINAL
            ,   TRANS_DT
            ,   (
                    SELECT      COUNT(*) - 1
                    FROM        Work.Trans AS T
                    WHERE       T.STORE_NUM = P.STORE_NUM
                            AND T.TERMINAL = P.TERMINAL
                            AND T.TRANS_DT >= P.START_DT
                            AND T.TRANS_DT <= P.END_DT
                ) AS TRANS_COUNT
    FROM        Work.Trans AS P
    ;


QUIT;
```

```
┌───────────┬──────────┬────────────────────┬─────────────┐
│ STORE_NUM │ TERMINAL │           TRANS_DT │ TRANS_COUNT │
├───────────┼──────────┼────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│      1111 │        1 │ 01Feb2013 10:46:04 │           0 │
│      1111 │        2 │ 02Feb2013 17:09:19 │           0 │
│      2222 │        3 │ 02Feb2013 17:10:30 │           0 │
│      2222 │        3 │ 02Feb2013 17:11:35 │           1 │
│      2222 │        3 │ 02Feb2013 17:13:26 │           2 │
└───────────┴──────────┴────────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

---

### UPDATE

If you don't want to use SQL, you can still do all of this from a DATA step. I'm not a SAS expert, but I've devised the following solution. It basically opens the dataset and loads the first record, then peeks ahead and counts records until the STORE_NUM or TERMINAL change, the TRANS_DT is greater than or less than the start and end dates we calculated already, or the EOF is reached. When one of these conditions are met, the next record is loaded and the logic is repeated.

For this to work, it is essential that the dataset be sorted appropriately (by STORE_NUM and TERMINAL and then by TRANS_DT *DESCENDING*). Otherwise, the peek operation will short-circuit and your counts will be incorrect.

So, first we sort:

```
PROC SORT DATA=Work.Trans;
    BY      STORE_NUM
            TERMINAL
            DESCENDING TRANS_DT
            ;
RUN;
```

Then we run the logic for reading the dataset<sup>1</sup>. There are many steps involved, so I used comments to explain each step of the process:

```
DATA Work.Trans2;

    FORMAT  STORE_NUM       4.0
            TERMINAL        1.0
            TRANS_DT        DATETIME18.
            TRANS_COUNT     6.0
            ;

    KEEP    STORE_NUM
            TERMINAL
            TRANS_DT
            TRANS_COUNT
            ;

    /* OPEN THE Work.Trans DATASET */
    TransId = OPEN( 'Work.Trans', 'IN' );

    /* ITERATE OVER ALL OBSERVATIONS IN Work.Trans */
    CURR_OBS = 1;
    DO WHILE(1);
        PUT 'CURR_OBS = ' CURR_OBS;
        /* LOAD NEXT OBSERVATION */
        NEXT_RC = FETCHOBS( TransId, CURR_OBS );
        IF (NEXT_RC ~= 0) THEN LEAVE;

        /* LOAD VALUES FROM THE CURRENT OBSERVATION */
        STORE_NUM = GETVARN( TransId, 1 );
        TERMINAL = GETVARN( TransId, 2 );
        CUSTOMER_NUMBER = GETVARN( TransId, 3 );
        TRANS_DT = GETVARN( TransId, 4 );
        START_DT = GETVARN( TransId, 5 );
        END_DT = GETVARN( TransId, 6 );
        TRANS_COUNT = 0;

        /* PEEK AHEAD TO COUNT TRANSACTIONS THAT OCCURRED WITHIN THE SPECIFIED
           TIME RANGE */
        PEEK_OBS = CURR_OBS + 1;
        DO WHILE(1);
            PUT 'PEEK_OBS = ' PEEK_OBS;
            /* PEEK AHEAD TO NEXT OBSERVATION */
            PEEK_RC = FETCHOBS( TransId, PEEK_OBS );
            /* IF THE EOF IS REACHED, EXIT THE CURRENT DO LOOP
               (STOP PEEKING) */
            IF ( PEEK_RC ~= 0 ) THEN LEAVE;

            PK_STORE_NUM = GETVARN( TransId, 1 );
            PK_TERMINAL = GETVARN( TransId, 2 );
            PK_TRANS_DT = GETVARN( TransId, 4 );

            IF PK_STORE_NUM = STORE_NUM AND 
               PK_TERMINAL = TERMINAL AND 
               PK_TRANS_DT >= START_DT AND
               PK_TRANS_DT <= END_DT
            THEN DO;
                /* IF THE STORE_NUM AND TERMINAL MATCH THE CURRENT OBSERVATION 
                   AND THE TRANS_DT IS WITHIN THE ACCEPTABLE RANGE THEN
                   INCREMENT TRANS_COUNT BY 1 */
                TRANS_COUNT + 1;
            END;
                /* OTHERWISE, EXIT THE CURRENT DO LOOP (STOP PEEKING AHEAD) */
                ELSE LEAVE;

            /* INCREMENT PEEK INDEX BY 1 */
            PEEK_OBS + 1;
        END;

        /* OUTPUT THE CURRENT RECORD ALONG WITH THE TRANS_COUNT TO
           Work.Trans2 */
        OUTPUT;

        /* INCREMENT CURRENT OBSERVATION INDEX BY 1 */
        CURR_OBS + 1;
    END;

    /* EXPLICITLY CLOSING THE Work.Trans DATASET IS OPTIONAL IN THIS CONTEXT,
       BUT GOOD PRACTICE */
    CLOSE_RC = CLOSE( TransId );
RUN;
```

Finally, sort the resulting dataset however you want. I've returned the dataset to the sort originally found in the source dataset (TRANS_DT *ascending*).

```
PROC SORT DATA=Work.Trans2;
    BY      STORE_NUM
            TERMINAL
            TRANS_DT
            ;
RUN;
```

The result is identical to the second SQL solution above. (If you liked the first solution, then just default TRANS_COUNT to 1 instead of 0)

```
┌───────────┬──────────┬────────────────────┬─────────────┐
│ STORE_NUM │ TERMINAL │           TRANS_DT │ TRANS_COUNT │
├───────────┼──────────┼────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│      1111 │        1 │ 01Feb2013 10:46:04 │           0 │
│      1111 │        2 │ 02Feb2013 17:09:19 │           0 │
│      2222 │        3 │ 02Feb2013 17:10:30 │           0 │
│      2222 │        3 │ 02Feb2013 17:11:35 │           1 │
│      2222 │        3 │ 02Feb2013 17:13:26 │           2 │
└───────────┴──────────┴────────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

This SQL-free approach may be faster in some scenarios. If you have no indexes setup and your data is broken up into small chunks so that you are only ever peeking ahead to a small percentage of records, then this could potentially be faster than a SQL subquery (running on SAS - a DBMS might be faster even without indexes). I've not tested it against a supermassive dataset so I have no way of verifying those claims.

<sup>1</sup> *I owe much of the "Trans2" code to the article* [Data Without (Step) Boundaries: Using Data Access Functions *by Felix Galbis-Reig*](http://www.nesug.org/proceedings/nesug07/cc/cc15.pdf)